# Zoom and center an image without cutting the borders

Tags: jquery, css, image, centering

I've tried many different things but none is working.

I have a picture (let say unknown height and width) and I want it centered (vertically and horizontally). The height and width is determined by the window size, but must not be more than the original height and/or width.

As an exemple, you can look at **Windows Live Photo Gallery**, when you double click on a picture. This is exactly what I need, in css/jquery. I don't know how to adjust the image to fit as I want in the page.

Thanks for any help.

I don't know the specific term since english is not my native language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know your image's size before hand (on the server side), the easiest way is to do it when rendering the HTML; use the `width` and `height` attribute of your `<img>` tag to set its size, and it's `margin-left` and `margin-top` to center it into a container. This will make it a lot better for the end user as he won't see the screen flicker when re-sized javascript side after the image is loaded. This is by far the best way to do this.

**Edit**: as stated in the comments, if you use the server side solution you might want to still use a javascript solution on $(window).resize(), so that the image stays centered and properly sized if the user change the window's dimensions.

--

However, since your question is for javascript, you need to work in two steps; first reduce the image height and width so as not to be larger than the window while keeping ratio, then in a second time apply some margin to center it both horizontally and vertically.

Here is an example of how you could achieve what you want, **note that this code is clearly not optimized and probably shouldn't be used as-is**, I leave it in its "verbose" way to keep it easier to understand.

The HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="main" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <img id="yourpic" src="http://domain.com/image.png" />
  </div>
</body>
```

The JS:

```
// we use the onLoad event so that your browser know the image dimension
$('#yourpic').load(function() {
    // cache your objects
    var $window = $(window);
    var $this = $(this);

    var tmp;

    // if the image has too much width reduce it, keeping its ratio
    if ($window.width() < this.width) {
        tmp = [this.width, this.height];
        $this.width($window.width());
        $this.height(tmp[1] / (tmp[0] / this.width));
    }

    // same for its height
    if ($window.height() < this.height) {
        tmp = [this.height, this.width];
        $this.height($window.height());
        $this.width(tmp[1] / (tmp[0] / this.height));
    }

    // now center it horizontally
    if ($window.width() > this.width) {
        $this.css('margin-left', ($window.width() - this.width) / 2);
    }

    // and vertically
    if ($window.height() > this.height) {
        $this.css('margin-top', ($window.height() - this.height) / 2);
    }
});
```

You can see it in example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RPCjE/2/ (chome img.onload event is [quite buggy](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7731) so if you are using this browser you might have to refresh with no cache).

Comment: No idea, I took the first big one from imgur's homepage: http://imgur.com/gallery/fWoCV

Comment: But if I render the image using PHP before sending it to the webbrowser, if the window is resized, PHP need to re-render the picture again and may slow down the user experience, what do you think? Nice picture ;)... And thanks for the code, I'll play around that.

Comment: @JeremyDicaire: render it using php, and add a $(window).resize() handler to resize in javascript when needed. You get the perfect rendering with no flicker, and in case of a resize it will adapt as needed.

Comment: @Lepidosteus: Sorry but I can't figure how to resize the image using $(window).resize... the image do not get bigger/smaller... Can you give me a hint please? (I already removed the $('#yourpic').load event on this part) THX